# How to get the default printer name in Silverlight OOB mode with trusted level?

Tags: silverlight

Now I know how to set default printer with printer name by AutomationFactory,

```
    var scriptNetwork = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Network");
    scriptNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter("Microsoft XPS Document Writer");
```

after I finish my printing to specified printer, I need to change the default printer back to the original, how can I get the original default printer name??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please,

```
private string GetDefaultPrinter()
{
    var oShell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    string sRegVal = "HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Windows\\Device";
    string sDefault = "";
    sDefault = oShell.RegRead(sRegVal);
    sDefault = sDefault.Split(new String[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
    return sDefault;
}
```